# How to scroll the bottom of pdf object element in html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdfviewer

I have a Pdf object on a page

```
<object data="data/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="700" height="900">
</object>
```

I need to scroll this pdf to the last page on page load.
At least in Fx, if there is not universal way for that. I see it uses pdfViewer in Firefox, but not sure how to get the viewer itself to ask it to scrolldown. The document is of varying length, I do not know the last page number.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the last page number, you could use `page` [PDF open parameter](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) in your pdf file path like this:

```
"data/test.pdf#page=50"
```

When the pdf load, it will show page 50.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the google document viewer, there is a method to load it at a specific page.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://pathtoyourpdf&embedded=true" onload="javascript:this.contentWindow.location.hash=':0.page.10';">
```

Where in ":0.page.10" 10 is the page number, zero based.